# What is the default transaction row level in Postgres and/or LOCK used by default in Sequelize.js

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, isolation-level, transaction-isolation, rowlocking

What is the default row-level lock mode used in PostgreSQL?
And because the question is related to Sequelize ORM, so, it would be nice to know which mode is used by default to avoid or modify my queries.

Comment: What do you mean with "*default row-level lock mode*" - the isolation level? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, for the isolation level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default isolation level in Postgres is `read committed`.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-READ-COMMITTED)

> *Read Committed* is the default isolation level in PostgreSQL

Comment: I will select this as the answer due to right now I don't remember well what I was trying to solve that day :/ , anyway thanks.